# Id not being passed through function call JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a password vault being served from a server for a special page on our intranet at work, but I'm having issues passing the ID through the `edit()` function into my script. Here is the applicable markup (as you can see it is contained in a `PHP` array. Everything, including the `id` is being served correctly (ie the ids at the source will read `n1` or `p7` etc...)):

```
<tr id='$OTHERInfo[0]'>
<td id='n$OTHERInfo[0]' onclick='edit(this)' contentEditable='false'>$OTHERInfo[1]</td>
<td id='u$OTHERInfo[0]' onclick='edit(this)' contentEditable='false'>$OTHERInfo[2]</td>
<td id='p$OTHERInfo[0]' onclick='edit(this)' contentEditable='false'>$OTHERInfo[3]</td>
<td id='d$OTHERInfo[0]' onclick='edit(this)' contentEditable='false'>$OTHERInfo[4]</td></tr>
```

Here is the script...it's very simple (it is contained at the bottom of the document):

```
<script>
function edit(id){
document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "white";
document.getElementById(id).style.color = "black";
document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");
} 
</script>
```

In the console the error message reads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

So obviously the ID is not getting passed correctly, but I don't know what to do. I've also tried just trying to "hard code" the ID into the function in the `onclick` like this: `edit(n$OTHERInfo[0])` but I have the same issue.

Comment: I think `edit(this)` sends the whole object not just the ID. So try doing `document.getElementById(id.id).style...` and see if that helps?

Comment: Use this instead document.getElementById(id)

Comment: `id` is a reference to the clicked element.

Comment: @CynePhoba12 THAT WORKED!! Thank you so much! It's the little things that get me almost all of the time. Post your answer so I can give you the credit :)

Comment: @AdamMcGurk No worries! The answer from CodeConfident below should do the same job, probably a cleaner way of doing at as well (because you're not having to look up the elements again) so give that one a go!

Comment: (edit: CynePhoba replied faster!) ...yea, better to just replace document.getElementById(id.id) with id since you already have the element.

Comment: Debugging tips. It's always good to check you're getting valid input i.e. `if (id === null)` and `console.log` your object to make sure your object is what you think it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'this' is the entire `<td>` element not just its id, so your script should read:

```
<script>
function edit(element){
    element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    element.style.color = "black";
    element.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I like the cleanliness of that answer! I'll accept it as soon as I can haha

Answer (score 1):

`id` at `edit` function is a reference to the clicked element

```
onclick='edit(this.id)'
```

or

```
function edit(id){
  id.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  id.style.color = "black";
  id.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are providing `edit(this)`. The keyword `this` references the actual element. It doesn't reference the ID of the element. You can revise your code without `document.getElementById` to work.

```
function edit(element) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    element.style.color = "black";
    element.setAttribute("contentEditable", "true");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td id='n$OTHERInfo[0]' onclick='edit(this)' contentEditable='false'>$OTHERInfo[1]</td>
```

If you pass `this` to `edit` function, you will use the entire element(i.e. the `<td>` element) as the parameter rather than its id.

You could try `onclick='edit(this.id)'`. This will give you the id of the `<td>` element as parameter.